# how to define a class of boolean functions with infix operators in F#?

Tags: filter, f#, infix-notation

Maybe it's already implemented in F# ?

basically i would like to define a class of generic filter functions with infix operators, so something which would look like

```
type Filter<'T> = ('T -> bool) with 
     static member (|*) (f:Filter<'T>) (g:Filter<'T>) = (fun x -> (f x) || 
     (g x)) // OR operator
```

but this is not the right syntax it seems

> Stopped due to error  System.Exception: Operation could not be
>   completed due to earlier error  Type abbreviations cannot have
>   augmentations at 2,5  Type abbreviations cannot have members at 3,19

thanks

Comment: error msg would be nice

Comment: @robkuz i included the error msg for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are defining there is a [type abbreviation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/type-abbreviations), which, as the errors will indicate, can neither have augmentations nor members. You could fix that by using a [single case discriminated union](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/designing-with-types-single-case-dus/):

```
type Filter<'T> = Filter of ('T -> bool) with 
     static member (|* ) (Filter f, Filter g) =
        Filter(fun x -> f x || g x) // OR operator
```

Of course, you now need to unwrap the predicate function prior to the boolean operation, and wrap the composed function again afterwards. A simple test...

```
let odd x = x % 2 <> 0
let big x = x > 10
let (Filter f) = Filter odd |* Filter big in [8..12] |> List.filter f
// val it : int list = [9; 11; 12]
```